# Update mongodb from php form

Tags: php, mongodb

Hi there im trying to update a nested array I have done some research and have come up with the following question but the answer isnt quite clear on how to update where x = this.

LINK 
[How to updated nested array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6953970/how-to-updated-nested-array)

```
$yourArray["experience"][1]["from"] = 2006;
```

That line looks like what I need but I need to figure out how to use the update part of it, this is my post script for my form.

```
$ID = $_POST["id"];
$NAMESTATE = $_POST["name"];
$REASON = $_POST["reason"];
require ('mongo.php');


if ($WISHNAMESTATE == "" and $ID == "")
{
    echo("OOPS SOMETHING WENT WRONG!");
    exit();
}
else
{
$m->update(array('_id' => $ID),(array('fields.NameState._0' => $NAMESTATE)));
   header("refresh:0;url=names_test.php");
```

My db looks like this.

```
array(
"_id"=>100000005,
"dclass"=>"Distributed",
    "fields"=>array(
"Name"=>array(
    "_0"=>"Testing",
),
"NameState"=>array(
    "_0"=>"PENDING",
),
 'setName': {
    '_0': 'test name'
```

So what this post needs to do is take the value NAMESTATE and update that field in the document with the matching ID, Please let me know if I am on the right track here.

Comment: I have done some more research and using this page http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10522347/mongodb-update-an-object-in-nested-array?rq=1 i have come up with this `$m->update({'_id' : $ID , 'fields.NameState._0' : $NAMESTATE});` but Dreamweaver is giving me a syntax error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$_POST` contains just String variables. If documents' `_id` field is Integer, you must be cast to int to `$ID`;

```
$m->update(array('_id' => (int) $ID),(array('fields.NameState._0' => $NAMESTATE)));
```